# PHP: passing a function with parameters as parameter

Tags: php, lambda

I'm not sure that silly question, but I ask:
So, if there is an anonymous function I can give it as another anonymous functions parameter, if it has been already stored a variable.
But, whats in that case, if I have stored only one function in a variable, and add the second directly as a parameter into it? Can I add parameters to the non-stored function?

Fist example (thats what i understand :) ):

```
$func = function($str){ return $str; };
$func2 = function($str){ return $str; };
$var = $func($func2('asd'));

var_dump($var);
// prints out string(3) "asd"
```

That makes sense for me, but what is with the following one?

```
$func = function($str){ return $str; };
$var = $func(function($str = "asd"){ return $str; });

var_dump($var);

/** This prints out:
object(Closure)#1 (1) {
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["$str"]=>
    string(10) ""
  }
}
But why?
*/
```

And at the end, can someone recommend me a book or an article, from what i can learn this lambda coding feature of php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$func` simply returns its argument, so:

```
$var = $func(function($str = "asd"){ return $str; });
```

is the same as:

```
$var = function($str = "asd"){ return $str; };
```

The fact that anonymous functions are instances of [Closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php#reserved.classes.closure) is an implementation detail [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) warn against relying on.  There's nothing special about Closure.  It can be implemented in regular PHP thanks to the [`__invoke`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke) magic method.

On my PHP 5.3.2 installation, Closure has a different representation.  The parameter is marked with an `"<optional>"` string.  Perhaps this is a formatting issue.

```
php > $func = function($str){ return $str; };
php > $var = function($str = "asd"){ return $str; };
php > var_dump($var);
object(Closure)#2 (1) {
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["$str"]=>
    string(10) "<optional>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In second example $func just returns the function set via parameters..

Easiest way to show you is this way..

```
$func = function($str){ return $str(); }; 
$var = $func(function($str = "asd"){ return $str; }); 

var_dump($var);
```

Note the () after 'return $str' in $func

**Reply to Comment:**

```
$func = function($str, $value){ return $str($value); }; 
$var = $func(function($str = "asd"){ return $str; }, 'efg'); 

var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Understand? The function is returned not executed. Thus the () after $str wil execute it.

Comment: yep, i understood, and how can add a value to the `$str` variable in the unnamed parameter, function?

Comment: Se my reply to your comment in the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$func = function($str){ return $str; };
$var = $func(function($str = "asd"){ return $str; });

var_dump($var);
```

First you define a function `$func` which simply returns the first parameter. So $var becomes `function($str = "asd"){ return $str; }`.

I can recommend the IBM article about closures and lambda functions http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-5.3new2/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $func = function($str){ return $str; };
```

Generates a Closure **object** with a [__invoke()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke) function.

This object is passed as a parameter in the second example.
And because the anonimimus function returns the input the var_dump() display the **function object** instead of the **result**.

Too bad chaining isn't supported (like in javascript)

```
 $func = function($str){ return $str; };
 $var = $func(function($str = "asd"){ return $str; }('test'));
 var_dump($var);
```

Could result in *"test"* but generates a **PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '('**